# Heroku, deploy de una app Vuejs muy simple me da errores

Tags: vue.js, heroku

estoy tratando se subir una app a heroku, el tema es que esta subida. Pero no se muestra nada, aquie dejo la  [url de la página](https://tiempo-actual.herokuapp.com/) . La pagina es una simple muestra que estaba probando de una api de tiempo para ver el clima actual de las diferentes ciudades del mundo.  La url de la pagina me indica que hay un error, y que mire en los **logs** posibles errores que tenga, y esto es lo que me sale:

```
2020-10-06T15:04:24.353711+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=tiempo-actual.herokuapp.com request_id=xxx fwd="xxx" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-10-06T15:04:24.582172+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=tiempo-actual.herokuapp.com request_id=xxx fwd="xxx" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-10-06T15:10:04.917200+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=tiempo-actual.herokuapp.com request_id=xxx  fwd="xxx" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-10-06T15:10:05.077135+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=tiempo-actual.herokuapp.com request_id=xxx fwd="xxx" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-10-06T15:10:06.968934+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=tiempo-actual.herokuapp.com request_id=xxx fwd="xxx" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-10-06T15:10:07.279803+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=tiempo-actual.herokuapp.com request_id=xxx fwd="xxx" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Mirandp por ahi podia ser uno de los problemas que necesite en el **package.json** dentro de la categoria **scripts** un comando llamado **start**, pues me imagino que es el que el servidor buscar para saber por donde empezar a arrancar el proyecto, lo puse y ademas otros comandos que vi que podian flatar, quedando la parte de los **scripts** asi :

```
 "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
    "postinstall": "npm run build",
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
```

Sin embargo, sigue sin funcionar, repito era una simple app para probar que funcione, asi evitaria problemas de compatibilidades desde un primer momento.
En este log :

```
2020-10-06T14:54:05.184937+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2020-10-06T14:54:07.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020-10-06T14:54:09.154615+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! missing script: start
```

Se puede observar que esta buscado el script start , yo lo tengo puesto pero no lo pilla.

---

### Respuesta al comentario de  'JackNavaRow'

```
"dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.20.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.2",
    "bootstrap-vue": "^2.17.3",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vue-axios": "^2.1.5",
    "vue-country-region-select": "^2.0.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11"
  },
```

¿Que mueva todos los de la parte devs al otro ?

Comment: el error y estoy casi seguro, mueve las dev-dependencies a dependency en tu package.json

Comment: @JackNavaRow cortando y pegando o con algun comando? no vaya a ser que e cargue algo